# Cannot initialise Recipient on Outlook MailItem in C# Winforms Application

Tags: c#, outlook

I am writing a class to send out emails through Outlook 2013 (15.0.4859). I have Outlook open in the background.

I tried the widely used code:

```
// Create the Outlook application.
Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

// Create a new mail item.
Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

// Set HTMLBody. 
//add the body of the email
oMsg.HTMLBody = "Test";
//Subject line
oMsg.Subject = "Test Subject";
// Add a recipient.

Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
// Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add("name@domanin.com");
oRecip.Resolve();

// Send.
oMsg.Send();

// Clean up.
oRecip = null;
oRecips = null;
oMsg = null;
oApp = null;
```

I get an error trying to initialise oRecips

> Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT))

I tried doing:

```
oMsg.Recipients.Add("name@domain.com")
```

but I get the same error.

How do I correctly specify recipients of the email?

Comment: Do any of these results help you?  https://www.google.com/search?q=Operation+aborted+%28Exception+from+HRESULT%3A+0x80004004+%28E_ABORT%29%29&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @rory.ap One of them was close as it was also related to Outlook (though error occurring in entirely different situation) , but suggested solution had no impact on my code.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error in a .NET Outlook Add-in (via Add-in Express) when reading `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_Recipients`. I do believe this is due to security issues. Happens only in certain corporate environments.

Comment: After the admin changed some Outlook security Group Policy settings, the error went away. See also [this related forum entry](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/311607ab-5e0f-42aa-bb13-49f122f7258a/systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-0x80004004-operation-aborted-exception-from-hresult?forum=outlookdev).